# How to properly link libraries with FreeBSD bmake?

Tags: makefile, freebsd, bsdmake, bmake

## Background

I'd like to compile a small program with some libraries and headers which live in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` (I installed them from ports).

I'm using the default FreeBSD [make(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) (which happens to be bmake(1) underneath).

## Makefile

So far my Makefile looks like this:

```
PROG_CXX=   client
MAN=
LDADD=  -lhip -lhop -lpthread
SRCS=   client.cc

CFLAGS+=    -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

## Question

Is there a better way to do it? I'm sure that `CFLAGS+=    -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib` is already automated by some `bsd.*.mk` but I couldn't find it. I've tried including `<bsd.lib.mk>` but to no avail.

## References

- [bsd.README](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/share/mk/bsd.README)
- [make(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports)
- [style.Makefile(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=style.Makefile&sektion=5&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)

Comment: `bsd.*.mk` are intended to be used in FreeBSD's own build system. Are developing your app as part of FreeBSD?

Comment: @arrowd It's not going to be a part of the FreeBSD project. It's just a FreeBSD-specific application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the community and I was told that what I'm doing with `CFLAGS` is actually right:

> The base system purposely excludes /usr/local/* from build stuff so your `CFLAGS` to include them, are the right thing.